# HTML Bookmark + CSS Overflow:Hidden - disappearing content?

Tags: html, css, bookmarks

In my page header, I have an image div with `overflow:hidden`.

In the content area, I have an bookmark anchor tag:

```
<a name="arghargh"></a>
```

At the top of the content area, I have a link to the bookmark:

```
<a href="#arghargh">go the the bookmark</a>
```

When I click the link, the content disappears, leaving only everything outside of the content div.

I found [this post](http://hdrlab.org.nz/blog/fixing-the-page-anchors-and-content-disappearing-under-the-header-problem/) describing the exact same issue. Based on that, I removed the `overflow:hidden`, and everything works fine, except that I need `overlow:hidden` for the page formatting to work correctly.

Help!

**Update**

It appears that, with `overflow:hidden`, the bookmark is causing the div to scroll internally, which moves all of the content up until the bookmark tag is at the top of the visible area. This is not cool.

Comment: Do you have link to the problem site?

Comment: It's not publicly accessible.

Comment: In that case can you upload a (preferably a simplified) example to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Updated question with more information

Comment: Can you at least show us the page's general HTML structure (and preferably a minimal working example)? Because I don't understand what you're saying. Does a div in the header with `overflow: hidden` cause the content area (another div?) to start scrolling? Jeaffrey's answer was a perfectly reasonable guess based on the limited info we got. And where is that anchor tag (and why are you using one at all as Stephan noted)?

Comment: I know it's quite old, but I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden` and add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` as last inner element to keep the page formatting to work correctly.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. These things aren't really equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `id="arghargh"` on the div instead of an anchor tag? Does the problem still occur then?